# kpfonts with eufrak

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to use kpfonts but with the standard mathfrak?
At first I thought it was nice to have a more readable font, but now I feel like the original one was actually better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to Euler Fraktur as the "standard mathfrak", it should be as easy as loading the eufrak package after the kpfonts package and undefining `\mathfrak` inbetween.

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\let\mathfrak\undefined
\usepackage{eufrak}
```

Edit: Corrected solution.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately it gives an error: Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/eufrak.sty:41 LaTeX Error: Command \mathfrak already defined.

Comment: Sorry, it should work now.

Comment: brilliant, I wonder if there's a way to switch between one font and the other

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can define a new command to access the fraktur letters in kpfonts like this, I think (after loading kpfonts): `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\kpfrak}{lettersA}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathfrak{U}{euf}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathfrak{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
```